# AngularJS Displaying a sorted $http response in template partial

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angular-ui-router

I'm currently working on a project that I need to sort the response by category and subcategory using Angular.

My controller currently looks like:

```
function($http, $stateParams) {
        let vm = this;

        $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                timeout: 10000,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose", 
                headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}, 
                params: {},
            }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                let documents = data.data.d.results;

                $.each(documents, function(i, item){
                    vm.data = sortDocuments(documents);
                })

            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

            function sortDocuments(documents) {
                return _.sortBy(documents, item => {
                    return {
                        category: item.Category,
                        subcategory: item.Subcategory,
                        documentURL: item.EncodedAbsUrl,
                        tags: item.Tags
                    }
                })
            };              
        })
```

I need to sort the category and subcategories in my view, but not sure how to go about doing it. My template partial currently looks like:

```
<div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Subcategory Name">
      <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Tags</th>
              <th>Link</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody ng-show="item.subcategory == 'Subcategory Name'" ng-repeat="item in documents.data">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>{{ item.tags.results }}</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="{{ item.documentURL }}">Open 
              Document</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
  </div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing in order to sort the view by category and subcategory?

Comment: Take a look at ng-grid, it should have all the features you are looking for: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/

Comment: Um, wrong question maybe?

Comment: @JoelCDoyle I've removed ng-model. At one point, there were inputs on this template, and the ng-model was left in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using _.map there. _.sortBy should do what you need.

http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

this should be pretty close:

```
vm.data = _.sortBy(data.data.d.results, document => { return document.Category + document.Subcategory } )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So that works very similar to what I was doing with _.map. My main issue is displaying the data in the view. Currently, I'm returning an array with 100 documents, when I have 700 that need to be sorted by category and subcategory in the view. How would I actually sort this in the view?

Comment: The code I posted should sort by category and subcategory.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The code you posted does indeed sort by category and subcategory. How would I modify the code template partial to display the sorted categories and subcategories. That's what I'm having a hard time trying to figure out. Your code does sort it, I'm just not sure how to filter it in the view. I'm using ng-show, which I know is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're after. Are you trying to only show a single category or place each category into its own table or something? I guess you want a div for each category? I'd use _ to extract the unique categories out into an array and then nest ng-repeats, one on the array of categories and another on the contents of vm.data. Then on your ng-repeat in the tr, use filter to match the current category.